# How to run multiple steps in aws data pipeline using aws console

Tags: amazon-emr, aws-data-pipeline

I have a use case of scheduling my spark jobs on EMR. Every time we will be spinning a new cluster and running spark job. I went through documentation provided by aws but those are not extensive enough to give clear picture of how to do it. If any one knows please share the solution with step by step guide.